# What's the equivalent to "Awaiting response" from bugtrackers on SE?

Tags: support, flags

When users of a bugtracker get asked a question like "Does this still happen?" (on old reports), "What do you mean by [...]?" or similar important questions and they don't answer in weeks or months, the report gets marked as "Awaiting response" (like [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/WEB-757?jql=resolution%20%3D%20%22Awaiting%20Response%22)).

Here I've seen cases where such a marking would also be useful, but it's not obvious to me what to choose. For example [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315217/setblock-will-not-work-in-distant-chunks) the question for the error message was not answered and without an answer the problem can't be solved (because nobody else can reproduce it). [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313269/minecraft-multiplayer-connectivity-issues) I asked questions and got no response, someone else wrote an answer with guesses, but that answer was neither voted nor accepted, nor commented on.

Should questions like these be...

- ...flagged as "unclear what you're asking"? I did that so far, because it seemed like the closest in the usual flag reasons, but that was apparently wrong and I was banned from flagging for a week.
- ...flagged as "in need of moderation intervention"? There I can leave comments to specify what I need.
- ...just left alone in case the user answers a long time later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question can't be solved without further input from the author, 'unclear what you're asking' actually seems the best fit; its description includes the sentence:

> or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

I've also seen people voting to close with a custom off-topic reason, but that's not an option you have when you can only *flag* to close. You could opt for a hybrid solution: flag to close as unclear **and** leave a comment why you're flagging. It might be that reviewers see a reasonably worded question (compared to other crap questions, Arqade gets a lot of them), don't understand why it's being flagged and vote to leave open (which resulted in your flag being declined).

<sub>note that one declined flag doesn't lead to flag bans; the ban kicks in when at least 25% of your flags in the last 7 days have been declined, and you've cast 10 or more flags in that period.</sub>

> flagged as "in need of moderation intervention"

I wouldn't choose that option. Yes, you can type a 'comment' there, but only ♦ moderators will get to read it. This is a problem the community can solve on its own; there's no need to involve a ♦ moderator.

> ...just left alone in case the user answers a long time later?

That's always an option. The [user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/126825/minerboyjosh) from your first example has visited the site today, so he is not on a holiday, but next time they might be. In any case, the question in its current state is [eligible for automatic cleanup after 30 days](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). There's absolutely no hurry to get this question closed/deleted.

Comment: "flag to close as unclear and leave a comment why you're flagging" The problem is that I can't add a comment if I choose that flag reason.

Comment: @Fabian that's no problem, just post a separate comment.

Comment: A question being the last comment is not enough? How should I word it then?

Comment: It's not (immediately) clear that it's an old comment.

Comment: How should I word it then?

Comment: "I'm flagging this question as 'Unclear what you're asking'; additonal information from the OP is needed to correctly answer it and the question seems to be abandoned by them."